# Get the newest directory to a variable in Bash

Tags: bash

I would like to find the newest sub directory in a directory and save the result to variable in bash.

Something like this:

```
ls -t /backups | head -1 > $BACKUPDIR
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
BACKUPDIR=$(ls -td /backups/*/ | head -1)
```

`$(...)` evaluates the statement in a subshell and returns the output.

Comment: Despite being accepted and much-upvoted there are several problems with this solution.  It doesn't work if the newest item in the directory is not a directory.  It doesn't work if the newest subdirectory has a name that begins with '.'.  It doesn't work if the newest subdirectory has a name that contains a newline.  [Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) complains about the use of `ls`.  See [ParsingLs - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a detailed explanation of the dangers of processing the output of `ls`.

Comment: It also fails if there is no directory within backups

Comment: It also does not get get the directory which was the most recently created, it gets the directory which is the most recently modified. Often they will be the same, but there is a clear distinction

Answer (score 27):

There is a simple solution to this using only `ls`:

```
BACKUPDIR=$(ls -td /backups/*/ | head -1)
```

- `-t` orders by time (latest first)
- `-d` only lists items from this folder
- `*/` only lists directories
- `head -1` returns the first item

I didn't know about `*/` until I found  [Listing only directories using ls in bash: An examination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352290/listing-only-directories-using-ls-in-bash-an-examination).

Comment: In answer to pjh's comment on the accepted answer "It doesn't work if the newest directory begins with '.'", which also relates to my answer. If you want to include folders starting with . (but exclude ./ and ../) you can change the ls to:   ls -td /backups/{.[^.],}?*/

Comment: This is mainly gor my own reference. Using --quoting-style=shell-escape seems to resolve many of the issues of ls raised by [ParsingLs - Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 9):

This ia a pure Bash solution:

```
topdir=/backups
BACKUPDIR=

# Handle subdirectories beginning with '.', and empty $topdir
shopt -s dotglob nullglob

for file in "$topdir"/* ; do
    [[ -L $file || ! -d $file ]] && continue
    [[ -z $BACKUPDIR || $file -nt $BACKUPDIR ]] && BACKUPDIR=$file
done

printf 'BACKUPDIR=%q\n' "$BACKUPDIR"
```

It skips symlinks, including symlinks to directories, which may or may not be the right thing to do.  It skips other non-directories.  It handles directories whose names contain any characters, including newlines and leading dots.

Comment: This is the only solution that doesn’t break arbitrarily for valid files.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think this solution is the most efficient:

```
path="/my/dir/structure/*"
backupdir=$(find $path -type d -prune | tail -n 1)
```

Explanation why this is a little better:

We do not need sub-shells (aside from the one for getting the result into the bash variable).
We do not need a useless `-exec ls -d` at the end of the `find` command, it already prints the directory listing.
We can easily alter this, e.g. to exclude certain patterns. For example, if you want the second newest directory, because backup files are first written to a tmp dir in the same path:

```
backupdir=$(find $path -type -d -prune -not -name "*temp_dir" | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: For me, this is not ordering the folders.

Comment: That's because it suffers from the same problem described in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21007729/147356).

Answer (score 2):

The above solution doesn't take into account things like files being written and removed from the directory resulting in the upper directory being returned instead of the newest subdirectory.

The other issue is that this solution assumes that the directory only contains other directories and not files being written.

Let's say I create a file called "test.txt" and then run this command again:

```
echo "test" > test.txt
ls -t /backups | head -1
test.txt
```

The result is test.txt showing up instead of the last modified directory.

The proposed solution "works" but only in the best case scenario.

Assuming you have a maximum of 1 directory depth, a better solution is to use:

```
find /backups/* -type d -prune -exec ls -d {} \; |tail -1
```

Just swap the "/backups/" portion for your actual path.

If you want to avoid showing an absolute path in a bash script, you could always use something like this:

```
LOCALPATH=/backups
DIRECTORY=$(cd $LOCALPATH; find * -type d -prune -exec ls -d {} \; |tail -1)
```

Comment: Despite the upvotes, this solution does not work.  `find /backups/* -type d -prune -exec ...` processes directories in the order they are produced when the shell expands `/backups/*`.  The order is determined by the names, not the timestamps.  The last directory listed will normally _not_ be the newest one.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU find you can get list of directories with modification timestamps, sort that list and output the newest:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@\t%p\0" | sort -z -n | cut -z -f2- | tail -z -n1
```

or newline separated

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -n | cut -f2- | tail -n1
```

With POSIX find (that does not have `-printf`) you may, if you have it, run `stat` to get file modification timestamp:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec stat -c '%Y %n' {} \; | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- | tail -n1
```

Without `stat` a pure shell solution may be used by replacing `[[` bash extension with `[` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757377/9072753).

Answer (score 0):

Your "something like this" was almost a hit:

```
BACKUPDIR=$(ls -t ./backups | head -1)
```

Combining what you wrote with what I have learned solved my problem too. Thank you for rising this question.

Note: I run the line above from GitBash within Windows environment in file called `./something.bash`.